stb image not linking properly
I trying studying in the learn opengl site and i have been in the chapter of loading models but the implementation of the code is not going ok because of the stb_image.h, when i try to put the library in the model.h file it does not work, giving the error of multiple initialization.
In the previous chapters i was using this code and working the functions to load images in the main file.
scr/aplicaition.cpp
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>
...

But i checked the code of the learn openGl course the declaration above as done in a separated stb_image.cpp so i corrected my code, but when i am trying to use stb_image.h in the Model.h, the functions to load images does not work like they did on the previous chapter.
scr/aplication.cpp
#include "../Model/Model.h"
...

scr/stb_image.cpp
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>

Model/Model.h
#include <stb_image.h>
...

In my head i think that the #define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION, works to turn the .h to a .cpp file, but still the #include in the Model.h shouldn't work as a second declaration, but instead just a forward declaration.

I'm afraid the question is not very clear. You get multiple definitions when you do what exactly? Just show the code you are using when you get the multiple definition errors.

I am unsure why you have a file named “scr/stb_image.cpp”, but in any case, as per the docs, you should only define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION in one of your source files. You have it in two (that you have shown us); this is the source of your multiple definitions.

@Dúthomhas I checked OpenGL course and it says to create a different file for the the define, and in the github it has a different file for it, and in the programs that it uses  #include<stb_image.h>, such as the model class it includes the std_image.h.

You have conflicting information, then. Only one file may define the implementation of the stb_image classes. The github file is just to make it easy — compile and link it into your project and you don’t need to worry about the define anywhere else.

@Tortadelimão It doesn't matter what the file is called. Or whether the file only has the header and the include or whether you have extra code as well. The important thing is that you have #define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION #include <stb_image.h> only once
